# How to run gRPC client to test the tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have been stuck here for some time now. I have created a simple neural network that predicts the earning from data set of video game sales. After I trained it for 2000 epochs, I exported the model as :

```
    model_builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("exported_model/001")

    inputs = {
        'input': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(X)
    }

    outputs = {
        'earnings': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(prediction)
    }

    signature_def = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs=inputs,
        outputs=outputs,
        method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
    )

    model_builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        session,
        tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature_def
        }
    )

    model_builder.save()
```

The model saved looks like :

[image]

Then I tried to serve the model locally using [`tensorflow model serve`](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup#installing_using_apt-get) by running the following command:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=4000 --model_name=mymodel --model_base_path=/home/suhail/tensorflow-stubs/exported_model
```

This started the model server with log as `2018-08-21 20:31:56.623311: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:327] Running ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:4000 ...`

Now I am trying to use this for prediction by using the gRPC client as explained here [tfserving-python-predict-client](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-tensorflow-models-9813b5a705d5)

Here is my predict.py

```
import numpy as np
from predict_client.prod_client import ProdClient
import random

HOST = '0.0.0.0:4000'
# a good idea is to place this global variables in a shared file
MODEL_NAME = 'mymodel'
MODEL_VERSION = 1

client = ProdClient(HOST, MODEL_NAME, MODEL_VERSION)

req_data = [{'in_tensor_name': 'inputs', 'in_tensor_dtype': 'DT_FLOAT', 'data': np.random.random_integers(1,200, size=(1,12))}]

prediction = client.predict(req_data, request_timeout=10)

print(prediction)
```

But on running `predict.py` there is an error that says:

```
<_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT,
   input tensor alias not found in signature: inputs. Inputs expected
       to be in the set {input}.)>

Prediction failed!
{}
```

What is this error? What am I doing wrong here?

**Here is the [complete code for my training script](https://gist.github.com/suhailgupta03/d231c53cc2a4065e279db6ebb646eb45) that exports the model.**

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple check: have you tried to replace 'in_tensor_name' to 'input' instead of 'inputs'? It seems the input name is incorrect.

By the way, I've implemented some clients for TF Serving a while ago and you can use PredictRequest object, which seems more intuitive IMHO.